# I cannot run a compiled program on Linux 19 but can on Linux 18 - Boost Problem

Tags: boost

I am building a cryptonote-based coin, I successfully compiled it on Linux 18, and it works perfectly.

I passed the compiled files to Linux 19 Tara, where I have installed the same dependencies as on the Linux 18 PC. When I ran it in the file browser, it did nothing at all. when I ran it through the command line, i get the following error message:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libboost_system.so.1.58.0: cannot open 
shared object file: no such file or directory
```

I installed "libboost-all-dev", so there should be no problem, since it ran on the Linux 18.

Comment: I mean a cryptonote-based anonymity coin

Comment: Short riddle: when you go to a shop, do you ask a 50 cent coke as you had in your youth, or do you ask for a coke? e.g. if moving binaries more modern versions of the OS, the library versions will change. Recompiling it is easier, there are more messier alternatives.

Comment: Oh okey, then I'll try, thanks for the recommendation, and sorry for my limited knowledge, I am relatively new to Linux

Comment: Do you mean "Linux Mint" everywhere you said "Linux"?

Comment: Yes I do, sorry if it is misleading

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have correct version of boost installed:

```
$ ldd <executable>
```

Comment: It says: libboost_system.so.1.58.0 not found, libboost_filesystem.so.1.58.0 not found, libboost_program_options.so.1.58.0 not found

Comment: You can try recompiling or upgrading/downgrading boost version, which might break some stuff, but apt should warn you about this, more info [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/428772/how-to-install-specific-version-of-some-package#428778).

Comment: I actually solved it by installing the same version to the second pc, the problem now is that when I run the program in the terminal with './program' it says: Illegal instrction (SIGILL) (core dumped memory image saved)